# Using ogr2ogr to export an Oracle Spatial table with measured geometries (3302) to a shapefile ignores the measure values

Tags: shapefile, ogr2ogr, oracle-spatial

I have an Oracle spatial table with measured geometries (SDO_GTYPE=3302) which I want to convert to a shapefile.
The command I am using is this:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" "tshapeARCM.shp" -lco SHPT=ARCM -dim XYM -nlt MULTILINESTRINGM OCI:{username}/{password}@{db_alias}:{table_name} -progress -skipfailures
```

I tried to use any combination of the lco/nlt/dim parameters but the shapefile insists on coming out with all M values as 0

I also checked the layer using ogrinfo and it reports:

```
1: {table_name} (3D Unknown (any))
```

Does this means that it does not recognize the 3302 geometry? Is this a bug in ogr2ogr or I am missing something?

Using GDAL 2.2.3 on a windows 10 laptop

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that M values are not supported by the OCI driver https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/2687